# Query also returns column with value 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
tb_question
**id_quest**    | **desc_quest**
    1           | How do you do...?
    2           | How are you...?

tb_answer
**id_quest** | **date_answer**
    1        |    2013/11/25
    1        |    2013/11/26
    1        |    2013/11/27
```

And my query:

```
SELECT 
q.id_quest,
q.desc_quest,
COUNT(a.id_quest) as total_answer -- count total answer by question

FROM tb_question q
INNER JOIN tb_answer a
ON q.id_quest = a.id_quest;
```

Result:

```
ID_QUEST  | DESC_QUEST              | TOTAL_ANSWER
   1      | How do you do...?       |    3
```

How could it do to return also question id = 2 with 0 count ?

Expected result:

```
ID_QUEST  | DESC_QUEST              | TOTAL_ANSWER
   1      | How do you do...?       |    3
   2      | How are you...?         |    0
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bfe7/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You have to use an outer join to get questions with no answers.
2. You left out the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT 
    q.id_quest,
    q.desc_quest,
    COUNT(a.id_quest) as total_answer
FROM tb_question q
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_answer a ON q.id_quest = a.id_quest
GROUP BY q.id_quest
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bfe7/16)

Comment: tks Barmar, actually the problem was a bit more complex and involved other tables, but your answer helped me to get what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

dont use inner join to select all idquest, inner join to produce subset of table

`SELECT tbq.id_quest,tbq.desc_quest,COUNT(tba.id_quest)
FROM tb_question tbq
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_answer tba ON tba.id_uest=tbq.id_quest
GROUP BY tbq.id_quest
ORDER BY tbq.id_quest`